# ASP.NET Routing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url-routing, friendly-url

I have a small task to do, and figured it would be better to start here than doing it wrong then coming here again.
I need to replace my URLs with a more friendly format as the following:
Current: www.MySite.com/default.aspx?userID=XX
I want it the users to type : www.MySite.com/user/(UserName)

Also, Current: www.MySite.com/default.aspx?userID=XX&ref#XX
I want the users to type: www.MySite.com/user/(UserName)/ref#{refno}

Thanks in advance

PS: I do not want to use Asp.net MVC.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the MVC Routing Feature without using MVC, as it's a separate component built on top of ASP.net.

There is an [article on 4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205221404/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051309-1.aspx) about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use routing in Webforms:

[Using ASP.NET Routing Without ASP.NET MVC](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205221404/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051309-1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I'd just use IIS7 URL Rewriting for that. Your mapping configuration can go in your web.config, and you wouldn't have to change your application at all.

- [Friendly URL tutorial](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/497/user-friendly-url---rule-template/)
- [IIS7 Rewriting and Web Forms](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/517/url-rewriting-for-aspnet-web-forms/)

Comment: Cool, and how can I do it?! :)